# Fastest Time for a Runner

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a time trial application which times runners over various running routes.

I have a table (`TT_DTL`) which has the following columns:

- `RecordID` - primary key
- `TT_HDRID` (fk) - this is linked to the `TT_HDR` table. I am only linking here to pull back a start date.
- `LapsedTime` (`time(7)`) - this is the runners time which they achieved
- `RunnerID` (fk) - this is linked to the `Runners` table and is used to pull back their name and gender.
- `RouteID` (fk) - this is linked to the `Routes` table and is used to pull back the route name.
- `DateTime` - the date and time the runner was scanned after finishing the race.
- `Age` - the runners age as per the date they ran

I am looking to create a script which shows the fastest time per runner for a selected route. The following query achieves this perfectly:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TT_DTL.LapsedTime ASC) AS No,
    Runners.FullName AS Name,     
    Runners.Sex, TT_DTL.Age, 
    MIN(TT_DTL.LapsedTime) AS Time, 
    Routes.RunningRouteDescription AS Route      
    --, TT_HDR.TTDate AS Date
FROM     
    TT_DTL 
INNER JOIN
    Routes ON TT_DTL.RouteID = Routes.RouteID 
INNER JOIN
    Runners ON TT_DTL.RunnerID = Runners.RunnerID 
INNER JOIN
    TT_HDR ON TT_DTL.TT_HDRID = TT_HDR.RecordID 
WHERE 
    TT_DTL.ROUTEID = 20001    -- @ROUTEID
GROUP BY 
    runners.FullName, tt_dtl.LapsedTime,     
    runners.sex, tt_dtl.age, Routes.RunningRouteDescription
    --,TT_HDR.TTDate
```

You will notice that I have commented out the `TT_HDR.TTDate` column.  If I add this in, which I need to do to get the actual date of the race, the records no longer group by the runner, rather displays all records for each runner.

Can someone please assist me to refactor this query to achieve the desired result?

The query noted is displaying multiple runners rather than the fastest (lowest) time per runner.

Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

Comment: T-SQL is a SQL dialect that is used by multiple products including Sybase, SQL Server, and Azure Synapse. What is the (R)DBMS product you are using here? [Edit] your question to tag that product, and (if relevant) the version tag for the product as well.

Comment: As an aside `Time` is a poor choice of datatype to store duration. It is perhaps not relevant for running, but there's a big limitation in that it has a maximum of 24 hours - although still relevant if you wanted to show the total time spent running over a certain period. Duration is much better stored as a decimal or an int. It is touched upon in this article: [Bad Habits to Kick : Choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)